# How to increasing scrolling area of UIScroll view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view with 5 images and some text views. It scrolls horizontally.

Now, when I scroll the content of the scroll view moves to an area.
How can I increase this limit?

I mean: I need to scroll more on single scrolling.

I have tried with increasing the `contentSize`.
It does not have the desired result: only the content of scroll view got increased.

Comment: Your question is not clear. To scroll further to the right you have to increase the scroll view's `contentSize`.

Comment: but if I increase the content size,the scroll view contains a lot of area with out any content

Comment: Right. I it is not clear what you want to increase.

Comment: @Mundi, it is about scroll more than the actual scrolling when the user scrolls once

Answer (score 2):

Try with code....

```
[scrollView setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set contentoffset property of scrollview in scrollview delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it on `viewDidLoad` method :: `scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);`

or whatever you want height.

Otherwise you can set it dynamically after all images & textviews will be loaded.

eg. `float h = [imagesCount * imageHeight] + [textVwCount *textVwHeight] + 100;`

then set to `scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, h);`

But keep in mind, always put height's value greater than actual size for ScrollView control.

Hopefully it will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

use UIScrollviewdelegate in .h file

and then use

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
```

in that function use

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollview.frame.origin.x+(value u want to scroll more) , 0) animated:TRUE];
```

The above code will allow ur scrollview to scroll more